# Run generic NUnit tests from command line of VS2015 SP1

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nunit-console, generic-test, vstest.console.exe

Problem: after installing **SP1** for **Visual Studio 2015** i cannot execute generic test from command line.

My command line and output is the next:
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio  14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe"   "S:\Tests\MyTests.dll" "/Settings:S:\Tests\MyTest.runsettings" "/ListTests:S:\Tests\MyTests.GenericTest" /InIsolation /Enablecodecoverage  /Logger:Console`

Generic test executes

```
"..\packages\NUnit.Runners.2.6.4\tools\nunit-console.exe"
```

with command line arguments

```
"..\MyNUnitProject.nunit" "/noshadow" "/process=Separate" "/Config=UnitTests" "/xml=..\nunit.UnitTests.results.xml"
```

vstest.console.exe returns follwing output:

```
[exec] Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 14.0.24720.0  
[exec] Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.  
[exec] The following Tests are available:  
[exec] Warning: No test is available in s:\Tests\MyTests.dll, s:\Tests\MyTests.GenericTest. Make sure that installed test discoverers & executors, platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again. Additionally, you can try specifying '/UseVsixExtensions' command if the test discoverer & executor is installed on the machine as vsix extensions and your installation supports vsix extensions. Example: vstest.console.exe myTests.dll /UseVsixExtensions:true  
[exec] Starting test discovery, please wait...  
[exec] Warning: No test is available in s:\Tests\MyTests.dll, s:\Tests\MyTests.GenericTest. Make sure that installed test discoverers & executors, platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again. Additionally, you can try specifying '/UseVsixExtensions' command if the test discoverer & executor is installed on the machine as vsix extensions and your installation supports vsix extensions. Example: vstest.console.exe myTests.dll /UseVsixExtensions:true
```

**Before installing SP1 for Visual Studio 2015 everything was working fine. I got test results and code coverage.**